# Communicate between Microsoft hosted agents?

Tags: android-emulator, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use an Android Emulator on a Windows and Linux machine in an Azure Pipeline.

Unfortunately, the Android Emulator only works on macOS, as Windows doesn't allow virtualization inside a VM and Linux has no hardware acceleration.

This brought me to the idea to [connect to an Android emulator running on Mac from the Windows/Linux host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows).

Is it possible to communicate between Microsoft hosted agents of Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

No. Each hosted agent is assigned on-demand at the time you queue a build or release. You can't reserve two agents at once and communicate between them.

It sounds like your requirements are such that you would be better served by provisioning your own private agent.

Comment: Has this changed, or is it still the case? The agents I want to use are in the same pipeline.

Comment: No, it hasn't. The behavior described is by design.